# how I can compare two set in a loop as a if condition

Tags: c++

I have  and 2 sets. I want to pick one element from the first set and compare it with all elements of the second set, and if it is not equal to non of them, do some thing! and I should repeat it for all element of the firs set! I tried this code:

```
int main() {
set<int> Y;
set<int> X;
for (auto iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); iter++) {

    for (auto iter1 = X.begin(); iter1 != X.end(); iter1++) {

        if (*iter != *iter1) {
            B[*iter1 - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it does not give me the right answer! I think I didn't write if condition in a right way!

Comment: What is `B`? Please provide a [MCVE] . What result are you expecting? How does that differ from what you actually get? There isn't enough information in your question to meaningfully answer it.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [std::any_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)?

Comment: How about using [`std::set::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::set::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) to tell if a value is a member of a set:

```
for (auto iter = Y.begin(); iter != Y.end(); iter++) {
    if (X.find(*iter) != X.end())
        B[*iter1 - 1] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have and 2 sets. I want to pick one element from the first set and compare it with all elements of the second set, and if it is not equal to non of them, do some thing!

What you are looking for is called [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) (as long as your containers are sorted and `std::set` is a sorted container, of course).

Just get rid of your loops, invoke the function above and find the elements that are in the first set and are not in the second one, then iterate them.
Complexity should be lower than the one of your approach in almost all the real world cases (you have at most `2(N+M-1)` comparisons vs a fixed number of `N*M` comparisons, where `N` is the size of the first set, `M` is the size of the second set).
The drawback is that it requires to allocate memory to store aside the elements to iterate. If it's a price you can pay mostly depends on the real problem, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

your implemented if-condition is just checking if the condition fails for any of the elements in the second set and so takes action. However, according to your discription, you want it to check the comparision to all elements of the second set before you take action:

```
for (auto iter=set1.begin(); ...) {
  bool equal_toany = False;
  for (auto iter1=set2.begin(); ...) {
     if (*iter == *iter1) {
        equal_toany = True;
        break;
     }
   }
   if (!equal_toany) {
     dostuff() // B[*iter -1] =1
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time! could you please tell me if the first element from the first list is not equal to non of the element of the second where I can writ B[*iter]=1, B is an array

Comment: as by answer of skypjack the std-lib provides also the convenience function ``std::set_difference` for this task. Still it might be instructive to see how to resolve with nested for-loops